# How to enable sonarlint(2.2.0) analyze in eclipse 4.5.2?

Tags: sonarlint

My Eclipse information is copied below.

upgrade the Eclipse to Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. 
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) 
Build id: 20160218-0600

I have installed sonarlint 2.2.0 successfully. 
But it can only be found in installed software.
It can not be enabled in project configure or project properties.

Comment: On English, sentences start with capitals and end with a "." (or "?").

Comment: upgrade the Eclipse to
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600

But sonarlint is still missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarLint 2.2+ requires Java 8.

Make sure that you are running Eclipse with Java 8.